# how to make a pendulum with this script?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a pendulum in roblox and this script doesnt work, it moves like it's bang on the side of an 8

```
local part = script.Parent
local runservice = game:GetService("RunService")
local additive = 1
local degree2 = 0
local degree = 0
local additive2 = 1

while runservice.Heartbeat:Wait(1) do
    if degree >= 45  then
    additive = -1
    additive2 = -1
    end
    if degree <= -45 then
    additive = 1
    additive2 = -1
    end
    
    degree += additive
    degree2 += additive2



    local x = 10 + math.cos(math.rad(degree))
    local y = 20 + math.sin(math.rad(degree2))
    local z = 1

    part.Position = Vector3.new(x,y,z)
end
```

i tried this to make it move until a 45 or -45 andle but it didnt work